# Returning the results of an async array in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm a novice with Javascript and am struggling to understand how or at least, how best to return array values to another script to assert agains their values.

The context is I want to use Puppeteer to obtain some string values from WebElement attributes and then use the Chai expect library to assert for correct values( or otherwise).

The code I have thus far is:

```js
//app.spec.js
const clothingChoice = await frame.$eval('#option-clothing-5787', e => e.getAttribute('value'));
const groceryChoice = await frame.$eval('#option-clothing-4556', e => e.getAttribute('value'));
const wineChoice = await frame.$eval('#option-clothing-4433', e => e.getAttribute('value'));
const voucherChoice = await frame.$eval('#option-clothing-3454', e => e.getAttribute('value'));

function testFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve([clothingChoice, groceryChoice, wineChoice, voucherChoice]);
  });
}

async function getChosenItemValues() {
  const [clothingChoice, groceryChoice, wineChoice, voucherChoice] = await testFunction();

  console.log(clothingChoice, groceryChoice, wineChoice, voucherChoice);

}

getChosenItemValues();

module.exports = getChosenItemValues;

};
```

I simply need to understand how to import the values that are currently simply printed out as:

```
1|clothing|option 1|grocery|option 1|wine|option 1|voucher|option
```

...into another file `test.js` in which I want to use chai to assert for their presence like so:

```
const [clothingEmailGrantedValue,emailRewardsNewsletterGrantedValue, emailGroceryOffersGrantedValue,telephoneRewardsDeniedValue ] = await app.spec.js(page, frame);
expect(clothingChoice).to.equal('1|clothing|option');
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to export directly your function and destructure your array inside your `test.js` file.

```
async function getChosenItemValues() {
  return await testFunction();
}

module.exports = getChosenItemValues()
```

inside your test.js file

```
const [clothingChoice, groceryChoice, wineChoice, voucherChoic] = require('./app.spec.js');

console.log(clothingChoice, groceryChoice, wineChoice, voucherChoice);
```